# Why does same size elements show different when zoom?

Tags: html, css

Here are two pseudo element before and after on same element. Both have 1px width. When I change the zoom of browser at some points it seems that their width is different.

```css
.main::after,
.main::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 17px;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: orange;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.main::after {
    left: 70%;
 }
 .main::before {
    left: 30%;
 }
.main{
  position: relative;
  padding:30px;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

You will be able to notice the issue by changing the browser zoom.

Comment: Please explain more, as i can't see any difference between two

Comment: @PHPGeek Did you check with by zooming in and out?

Comment: yes, both are same on zooming too

Comment: i think it is about your monitor pixels

Comment: May be is a problem with your browser.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi I am using latest chrome version

Comment: @A.Anvarbekov Maybe. But my client also see this issue on his screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a well known phenomenon.

It comes about because the system is trying to match one CSS pixel onto a screen which uses several screen pixels to hold one CSS pixel.

This can lead to edge effects (sort of like rounding errors) when the user zooms in or out. At certain zoom levels it can match a whole number of pixels, but at others it has to decide whether to leave out (or include) some screen pixels.

If you make your bar have 2px (CSS) width then at least on my system while I do see the phenomenon at 90% and 110% zoom I don't see it on others.

```css
.main::after,
.main::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 17px;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: orange;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.main::after {
    left: 70%;
 }
 .main::before {
    left: 30%;
 }
.main{
  position: relative;
  padding:30px;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: Isn't there any better and permanent solution. I can even use js to solve this.